# How to debug ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-keyvault

When trying to use `ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault` I'm getting the following error:

> 00:01:41 ERR] An error occurred while reading the key ring.
>   Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Models.KeyVaultErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
>      at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient.WrapKeyWithHttpMessagesAsync(String vaultBaseUrl, String keyName, String keyVersion, String algorithm, Byte[] value, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClientExtensions.WrapKeyAsync(IKeyVaultClient operations, String keyIdentifier, String algorithm, Byte[] key, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultXmlEncryptor.EncryptAsync(XElement plaintextElement)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultXmlEncryptor.Encrypt(XElement plaintextElement)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.XmlEncryptionExtensions.EncryptIfNecessary(IXmlEncryptor encryptor, XElement element)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager.Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.Internal.IInternalXmlKeyManager.CreateNewKey(Guid keyId, DateTimeOffset creationDate, DateTimeOffset activationDate, DateTimeOffset expirationDate)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager.CreateNewKey(DateTimeOffset activationDate, DateTimeOffset expirationDate)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.CreateCacheableKeyRingCore(DateTimeOffset now, IKey keyJustAdded)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.Internal.ICacheableKeyRingProvider.GetCacheableKeyRing(DateTimeOffset now)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.GetCurrentKeyRingCore(DateTime utcNow)

I am trying to use the method like this:

```
            services.AddDataProtection()
            .SetApplicationName("APPLICATIONNAME")
            .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(container, "keys.xml")
            .ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault(KeyVaultClientFactory.Create(), "https://KEYVAULTNAME.vault.azure.net/keys/DATAPROTECTIONKEY/");
```

Things I have checked:

1. Application in KeyVault has Wrap/Unwrap permissions (I have enabled ALL permissions just to try to get this working)
2. The code above works without `ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault`
3. `KeyVaultClientFactory.Create()` returns a valid `KeyVault` that can retrieve secrets.
4. The (RSA) key is enabled and exists in the KeyVault - Permitted operations on the key are also all enabled.

I'm now at a loss as to how to debug this further.  I assume I'm missing something obvious, any advice/suggestions would be welcome!

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you to change the implementation like below:

```
{
  "DataProtection": {
    "KeyVaultKeyId": "https://mykeyvaultname.vault.azure.net/keys/DataProtectionKey/bfc1bda979bc4081b89ab6f43bad12b8"
  }
}

var kvClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(_tokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

services.AddDataProtection()
    .ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault(kvClient, settings.KeyVaultKeyId);
```

and please ensure to provide the app with **Unwrap** Key and **Wrap** Key permissions to the key vault. Please note that t takes time to reflect changes sometime after giving permission.

You can take a look at the reference code here:

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/6f197a9e5d08477b598826e0d028019c9d62ad82/src/DataProtection/AzureKeyVault/src/AzureDataProtectionBuilderExtensions.cs

Additional reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.2

https://joonasw.net/view/using-azure-key-vault-and-azure-storage-for-asp-net-core-data-protection-keys

This is how my startup.cs looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using KeyVaultSample.Data;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault;
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AzureStorage;


using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.Rest;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;

namespace KeyVaultSample
{
    public class DataProtectionSettings
    {
        public string KeyVaultKeyId { get; set; }
        public string AadTenantId { get; set; }
        public string StorageAccountName { get; set; }
        public string StorageKeyContainerName { get; set; }
        public string StorageKeyBlobName { get; set; }
    }
    public class Startup
    {
        private readonly AzureServiceTokenProvider _tokenProvider;

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            _tokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            var settings = Configuration.GetSection("DataProtection").Get<DataProtectionSettings>();

            var kvClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(_tokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

            services.AddDataProtection()
                .ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault(kvClient, settings.KeyVaultKeyId);
            // Replicates PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage
            // There is no overload to give it the func it ultimately uses
            // We need to do that so that we can get refreshed tokens when needed
            services.Configure<KeyManagementOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.XmlRepository = new AzureBlobXmlRepository(() =>
                {
                    // This func is called every time before getting the blob and before modifying the blob
                    // Get access token for Storage
                    // User / managed identity needs Blob Data Contributor on the Storage Account (container was not enough)
                    string accessToken = _tokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://storage.azure.com/", tenantId: settings.AadTenantId)
                 .GetAwaiter()
                 .GetResult();
                    // Create blob reference with token
                    var tokenCredential = new TokenCredential(accessToken);
                    var storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(tokenCredential);
                    var uri = new Uri($"https://{settings.StorageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net/{settings.StorageKeyContainerName}/{settings.StorageKeyBlobName}");
                    // Note this func is expected to return a new instance on each call
                    var blob = new CloudBlockBlob(uri, storageCredentials);
                    return blob;
                });
            });
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
                .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();


            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Given your detailed response, I'd like to accept your answer.  Can you please add "Check the user that the application is authenticating as"?  My problem turned out to be that by default when I run via VS, in Azure IAM, I'm me!  Not the application...  So add the extra infor to your answer and I'll accept.  Thanks again for the details, made me rethink what I was doing!